# Android Google Maps v2 inside Scrollview shows gray tiles on some devices

Tags: android, google-maps

There is Android Google Maps v2 inside Scrollview
It works on many devices but shows gray tiles on some devices
API KEY is **Correct**,

To use Google Maps V2 inside Scrollview should to use custom class extends **SupportMapFragment**, Like This :

```
public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

And also set :

```
    ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTouch() {
                mScrollViewDa.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        });
```

The image bellow taken by users, **Android version** : **4.2.2** , **Device** : **Samsung Grand 2**

App tested on : **Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1" : 4.0.3** And **Asus Fonepad 7" Tablet : 5.0.1** And **Works well**

```
android:minSdkVersion="10"
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on this devices?

Comment: Yes, Customers told me Google Map works well on other apps , so Not for me

Comment: there should be the logcat for that device saying something (at least in warning filtering mode).
You can see the Google logo so I'm quite confident it is ok with Keys.
Just to be sure: Same country, connection ok, and Samsung Grand 2 has OpenGL2 support and working ok (no issues with games etc..) ?

Comment: @HK to be sure, try last play services 7.8.0

Comment: @Heyyou   Display ON 7inch, 10inch and lower, custommer lives in Iran, also in other cities tested and works well, map shows Google logo and plus and mines buttons inside gray area

Comment: can they provide you a logcat / error code / send error report with the error?  if not, and the buttons (MAP UI) are showing, it might be that the Device doesn't have enough power to load both the scrollview and the map, i'd try forcing Hardware accelelartion on that activity.  also, some methods were deprecated since maps V2 was released so there might be a problem here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases) if samsung decided to remove deprecated methods or disabled them and you still use them, like the getMap().

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem I have taken a different approach.

Yes, you're right that you cannot have a map directly into a ScrollView... but you can have a FrameLayout and replace it at runtime with the map. Like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
    android:id="@+id/mapViewDetail"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
    tools:context="com.yourpackage.app.HomeActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Then I have created a custom map because I needed some "tweak" (you can avoid this step if you are fine with the default map):

```
public abstract class MiniMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        initMap();
        return v;
    }

    public abstract void initMap();
}
```

Then, in the fragment I just added:

```
    MiniMapFragment mMapFragment = new MiniMapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void initMap() {
            googleMap = getMap();
            getMap().getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            getMap().getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }
    };

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapViewDetail, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: Touch is not my problem, that's gray tiles until zoom buttons loaded

Comment: so, just use only the upper part of the comment ;)

Comment: user select position by touch, i can not disable it

Comment: I've deleted the "touch part", use only the remaining.. :)

Comment: can you please tell me about bottom_layout on -> android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"

Comment: it's just positioning, you can remove that line

Comment: what is "mMapFragment" on -> fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapViewDetail, mMapFragment); min SDK 10 and Class extends FragmentActivity

Comment: I've added the missing code. However, you can not use the minimap and use directly the mapfragment if you are fine with the default settings

Comment: It doesn't works, only show Lat 0 , Lon 0 And crash after touch

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this will answer your question, but it is worth investigating.

From your question and the comments, it appears to be a user in Iran on a particular device that is receiving the grayed out maps.  As I am not sure of the user's exact location, I have done some research on the accessibility of Google Maps in Iran and surrounding areas.
It is possible this user is trying to locate maps that are intentionally grayed out.

[Satellite map images with missing or unclear data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_map_images_with_missing_or_unclear_data)

Not all things are shown on Google Maps.

[Blurred Out: 51 Things You Aren't Allowed to See on Google Maps](http://www.itsecurity.com/features/51-things-not-on-google-maps-071508/)

There were problems a couple of years ago with consumers using Google in Iran and Iran wanting to create an Islamic Earth Map.

[Iran plans 'Islamic Google Earth'](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/apr/10/iran-plans-islamic-google-earth)

However, this seems to have been resolved with people having access to Google maps in that area.

This is also a map of the US military bases near Iran. Of which there are many and are at least likely to be blurred, if not grayed out.

[American Military Bases Near Iran](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zQVqvB9UmUTc.kCl6RXZmRmIs)

Also in neighbouring Iraq, there are issues with outdated aerial footage.

[when Iraq will get new satellite imagery update](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/map-maker/16OgkhUUMzk)

Also, with Iran's Internet Censorship policy and use of 'Smart Filtering'

[Iran expands 'smart' Internet censorship](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/12/26/us-iran-internet-censorship-idUSKBN0K40SE20141226) I am not sure if this would affect the access to Google Maps in some areas.

I would suggest asking for the users specific location, or asking if the maps appear in some places and not others.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

The [Galaxy Grand Duos (GT-I9082)](http://samsung-updates.com/galaxy-grand-duos-gt-i9082-gets-android-4-2-2-update/) has only recently been updated to 4.2.2.

There are [multiple issues with the jelly bean update for the Samsung Grand 2](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Android%20version%20%3A%204.2.2%20%2C%20Device%20%3A%20Samsung%20Grand%202&oq=Android%20version%20%3A%204.2.2%20%2C%20Device%20%3A%20Samsung%20Grand%202&aqs=chrome..69i57.501j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=Android%20%204.2.2%20%20%20Samsung%20Grand%202%20issues)

If your user has recently upgraded his phone, it may be worthwhile checking into this.
Although the following link isn't specific to google maps, it is still useful.
[Samsung Galaxy Grand: Slow Performance after JB 4.2.2 upgrade.](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-1-4-2-4-3-jelly-bean/362643-samsung-galaxy-grand-slow-performance-after-jb-4-2-2-upgrade-2.html)

Beyond investigating the particular device and any issues I've mentioned previously, there is not much else I can offer you at this stage.

Comment: Other apps use map as well, my App works to me but not on city of customers

Comment: i have an app and i use it very well, Google's map is loaded in my app and i am in Tehran city of Iran, but my customer can't view Google's map in my app, he is in Yazd another city of Iran. notice: he can view Google's map in other app can you help me ?